# Serve static content on root and rest on /api

Tags: http, go, httprouter

I'm using [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) for parsing some parameters from the path in api calls:

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.GET("/api/:param1/:param2", apiHandler)
```

And wanted to add some files to the root (`/`) to serve. It's just `index.html`, `script.js` and `style.css`. All in a local directory called `static`

```
router.ServeFiles("/*filepath", http.Dir("static"))
```

So that I can go with the browser to `localhost:8080/` and it will serve `index.html` and the `js` from the browser will call the `/api/:param1/:param2`

But this path conflicts with the `/api` path.

`panic: wildcard route '*filepath' conflicts with existing children in path '/*filepath'`

Comment: From this issues https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter/issues/73, you can't achieve it easily using  httprouter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others pointed out, this is not possible using only `github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter`.

Note that this is possible using the multiplexer of the standard library, as detailed in this answer: [How do I serve both web pages and API Routes by using same port address and different Handle pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493820/how-do-i-serve-both-web-pages-and-api-routes-by-using-same-port-address-and-diff/47494191#47494191)

If you must serve all your web content at the root, another viable solution could be to mix the standard router and `julienschmidt/httprouter`. Use the standard router to register and serve your files at the root, and use `julienschmidt/httprouter` to serve your API requests.

This is how it could look like:

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.GET("/api/:param1/:param2", apiHandler)

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
mux.Handle("/api/", router)

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux))
```

In the example above, all requests that start with `/api/` will be forwarded to the `router` handler, and the rest will be attempted to handle by the file server.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I didn't find the so question you've mentioned. So this is a duplicate.

Comment: @microo8 Not a duplicate, as the other question seeks to achieve this using only the standard lib (where this is possible), and you were asking how to do it with `julienschmidt/httprouter`.