# Serving favicon.ico with JulienSchmidt httprouter

Tags: go

I can get favicon.icon with the standard `net/http` package but am having trouble with `julienschmidt/httprouter`. This is what I'm trying and am receiving a 404 error for the favicon.ico file.

```
import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main(){
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", index)
    router.POST("/", login)
    router.GET("/logout", logout)
    router.GET("/favicon.ico", faviconHandler)
    router.ServeFiles("/stuff/*filepath", http.Dir("stuff"))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func faviconHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
     http.ServeFile(w, r, "/stuff/images/favicon.ico")
}
```

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Serve static content on root and rest on /api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259630/serve-static-content-on-root-and-rest-on-api/48260135#48260135).

Comment: Does the order matter? What happens when you add the root path handler last? Does /logout work as expected?

Comment: Ah. I highly doubt that you have a file called "/stuff/images/favicon.ico" in your filesystem. You probably want to remove the leading slash to make the name relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the leading slash from `stuff/images/favicon.ico`. Thanks @Peter.

```
import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main(){
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", index)
    router.POST("/", login)
    router.GET("/logout", logout)
    router.GET("/favicon.ico", faviconHandler)
    router.ServeFiles("/stuff/*filepath", http.Dir("stuff"))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func faviconHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
     http.ServeFile(w, r, "stuff/images/favicon.ico")
}
```